# Filter by date using lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda, sql-server-2008-r2

I am jumping into building an ASP.NET MVC site and I am stuck on a probably simple issue. I am attempting to filter a query by date using a lambda expression. The other ways I have attempted to filter have been successful. Here is what I am trying to accomplish. The data is stored in a SQL Server 2008 R2 database with a `date` data type. I am not sure if this is why the results will not display.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Project.Models;

public class CreateController : Controller
{
    // GET: Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var dt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);           
        var db = new Models.Entities();

        var apps = db.tableName.Where(x => x.col1 == dt);                                        
        return View(apps.OrderBy(x => x.col2));
    }
}
```

And my view

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.table1>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Project";
}
    @foreach (var apps in Model)
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>col z</th>
                <th>col x</th>
                <th>col y</th>
                <th>col w</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>@apps.col1</td>
                <td>@apps.col2</td>
                <td>@apps.col3</td>
                <td>@apps.col4</td>    

            </tr> 
        </table>
    }
```

Comment: what is the sample data? probably what you wanted were `db.tableName.Where(x => x.col1 >= dt);`

Comment: If you want date only use x => x.col1.Date == dt.Date

Comment: It's difficult to guess what result you are expecting from what you have entered. You state that you have successfully filtered previously, but not why you are not successful now? What is the expected outcome from a fixed input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the looks of your code the c# datatype is DateTime, and the one in your database is Date.

you probally want to change your code in youre create function as

```
var dt = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-10);
```

now the code is only Date, without the time!

Comment: Use `DateTime.Today` and don't include the time in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

```
//per lordkain:
var dt = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-10); 

//per Yuliam Chandra:
db.tableName.Where(x => x.col1 >= dt);
```